# PhotoImage not iterable error in Jupyter notebook but not Idle3

Tags: tkinter, jupyter-notebook, python-idle

When I run the following code using idle3 it works fine

```
skin_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
skin_patch = tk.Label(root, image=skin_image)
skin_patch.image = skin_image
```

But in Jupyter notebook I need to and master=root to ImageTk.PhotoImage

```
skin_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im, master=root)
skin_patch = tk.Label(root, image=skin_image)
skin_patch.image = skin.image
```

otherwise I get an image does not exist error. I found the master=root solution by searching but there was no explanation as to why it is needed, nor why in Jupyter and not in Idle3.
Any light shed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try running your code directly with python, without involving IDLE, to see if IDLE has anything to do with the behavior.  This is fundamentally a tkinter question.  Tag added.

Comment: The Idle3 code works fine from the command line. It also now works fine in Jupyter Notebook. I can only assume note book was hanging on to some previous state - although I did restart the kernel. It would be good to know if assigning the image a master is good practice.